# pivoting pandas dataframe with all string data in each column

Tags: python, pandas, reshape

Sample dataframe:

```
Name   Attribute     Response
Joe    A             Yes
Joe    B             smoking 
Joe    B             headache
Mary   A             Null
Mary   B             Never
Bob    C             Today
Mary   A             Tomorrow
```

I have tried for several hours and searching through all apparently similar SO questions to pivot this df to the below desired output.  Note, Joe and Mary have more than one row in which the Attribute is the same, but the response is different.

Desired output

```
Name    A                    B                     C
Joe    Yes                   smoking, headache     Null
Mary   Null, tomorrow        Never                 Null
Bob    Null                  Null                  Today
```

Again, to reiterate, I have looked through every SO response regarding reshaping dataframes from long to wide and none of them involved this precise question.  Furthermore, each of those responses involved answers which I implemented and all resulted in errors, either a Value Error or Data Error, especially an error stating the index contained duplicate values.  So, your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do `.pivot_table()` with `aggfunc=list`:

```
print(
    df.pivot_table(
        index="Name", columns="Attribute", aggfunc=list, fill_value="Null"
    ).droplevel(0, axis=1)
)
```

Prints:

```
Attribute                 A                    B        C
Name                                                     
Bob                    Null                 Null  [Today]
Joe                   [Yes]  [smoking, headache]     Null
Mary       [Null, Tomorrow]              [Never]     Null
```

---

Or if you don't want lists:

```
print(
    df.pivot_table(
        index="Name",
        columns="Attribute",
        aggfunc=",".join,
        fill_value="Null",
    ).droplevel(0, axis=1)
)
```

Prints:

```
Attribute              A                 B      C
Name                                             
Bob                 Null              Null  Today
Joe                  Yes  smoking,headache   Null
Mary       Null,Tomorrow             Never   Null
```

---

EDIT: To rename indices:

```
df = df.pivot_table(
    index="Name",
    columns="Attribute",
    aggfunc=",".join,
    fill_value="Null",
)

df.index.name = ""
df.columns.name = ""
```

Comment: I tried the suggestion designed to produce a string instead of list.  Unfortunately, it threw this error.  "ValueError: Cannot remove 1 levels from an index with 1 levels: at least one level must be left."

Comment: On it.  Trying that now.  The list version appears to have worked.  Thanks so much for checking out my question!

Comment: Removing the .droplevel(0, axis=1) part put the strings Name, Attribute and Answer into the column values.  :)

Comment: @JohnTaylor It's just index name. You can try after `df.index.name = ""` and `df.columns.name = ""` to rename them. See my edit.

Comment: Not the column headers, actually into the dataframe there are listing of those terms in a list format in many of the various rows. That is what I meant.  I wasn't clear.

Comment: @JohnTaylor Does your dataframe has more columns? You can do `df = df[["Name", "Attribute", "Response"]].pivot_table( ... )` to pivot only these 3 columns.

Comment: I have created a subset of the original df to only have those columns.